# Как добавить фильтр по связанной таблице в yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

Друзья, есть такой виджет, созданный по ходу выполнения видеоурока. Возможно я что то упустил, но уже второй день не могу найти причину ошибки, которая заключается в том, что добавленный фильтр никак не хочет отображаться в виде index.php, сгенерированном CRUD-ом. Т.е. input не отображается.

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

        'id',
        [
            'attribute' => 'category_id',
            'filter' => Category::find()->select(['name', 'id'])->indexBy('id')->column(),
            'value' => function(Product $product){
                return $product->category->name;
            },
        ],
        [
            'attribute'=>'name',
            'filter' => Product::find()->select(['name','id'])->indexBy('id')->column(),
            'value' => function(Product $product){
                return $product->name;
            }
        ],
        'content:ntext',
        'price',
        [
            'attribute' => 'Tags',
            'filter' => Tag::find()->select(['name', 'id'])->indexBy('id')->column(),
            'value' => function(Product $product) {
                return implode(', ', ArrayHelper::map($product->tags, 'id', 'name'));
            },
        ],
        [
            'attribute' => 'active',
            'format' => 'boolean',
            'filter' => [0 => 'Нет', 1=> 'Да'],
        ],
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]); ?>
```

Comment: Интересует фильтр по Tags... именно это поле не является родным для виджета и именно для него не отображается filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из кода ясно, что у модели множественная связь с тегами `Tags` (hasMany). Чтобы была возможность производить по ним поиск, нужно учесть 2 момента:

**1)** явного аттрибута `tags` (поля в БД) у модели нет, есть только геттер `getTags()`, по-этому `searchModel` не знает, что мы от него хотим, пока не добавим в неё публичное свойство, в котором будет храниться введённый в поле фильтра текст:

```
public $tags; // сюда будет попадать текст, введённый в input фильтра
```

также не забудьте добавить его в `rules` для валидации вводимых данных.

**2)** чтобы поиск действительно работал, в `search` модели нужно дополнить запрос в БД примерно следующим образом:

```
$query = Product::find()->joinWith('tags');

$query->andFilterWhere(['LIKE', Tags::tableName() . '.name', $this->tags]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Часто возникала подобная проблема, в основном ошибка была в модели поиска которую передавал в GridView, (например в вашем случае отсутствия обявления атрибута Tags) в $searchModel, в таких случаях мне очень помогает [этот пост](https://nix-tips.ru/yii2-sortirovka-i-filtr-gridview-po-svyazannym-i-vychislyaemym-polyam.html). Хотя я склонен предположить что ошибка в большой буква в названии атрибута, попробуйте tags вместо Tags в итоге у вас должно получится:
 `[
            'attribute' => 'tags',
            'filter' => Tag::find()->select(['name', 'id'])->indexBy('id')->column(),
            'value' => function(Product $product) {
                return implode(', ', ArrayHelper::map($product->tags, 'id', 'name'));
            },
        ],`